# Similarly to How Photos Have Meta Data, Does Audio As Well?

Tags: audio

There have been cases where a photo's meta data was used to track people who posted the photo...Is this the same with audio? Is there a way to wipe this meta data?

Also, what about when this audio is uploaded to Soundcloud or Youtube? Is the meta data only seen by Soundcloud because they convert it to their format, or would listeners be able to download the audio and view the meta data?

Comment: [Apparently you can use powerline hum contained in audio recodings to figure out when it was recorded](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-20629671)

Comment: As regards soundcloud or YouTube, try it. Pop in some meta data and see if it's there when you download it again.

Comment: Quick question - what types of metadata worry you?

Comment: I strongly recommend purging metadata locally and not relying on the hoster to do it for you.

Comment: MP3 files are tagged with meta data.

Comment: The metadata you are referring to typically has NOTHING to do with "who" posted files.  Tracking who uploaded a file is relatively simple assuming you have authority to do so.  This also depends on where it is uploaded.  It is simple for a server to log an IP and associated user ID when a file is logged.  After that, if there is any legal reason to do so they can track down the owner of the IP (your ISP) and then through them find you.  Unless... you are for some reason referring to geotagging.

Comment: Who downvoted this? If so, please provide explanation.

Also, I am talking about personal meta data. @Goblinlord hinted at part of it "geotagging" or other personal information (name of computer it came from, etc.)

Comment: @User50178 Metadata is not placed in files u less you put it there.  Geotagging in photos is typically only added if an option is set to do so.  Neither typically has a "user who created" field unless you explicitly put it there.  Tracking down people who do create or start distributing files is normally done using other methods of tracking.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - audio also has meta data. Pretty much every digital audio format has some meta data - this is often called an [ID3 tag](http://id3.org/) ([Wikipedia article on ID3 tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3)) but is also supplemented with the [Vorbis Comment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis_comment) meta data in the instances of Vorbis, FLAC, Theora, Speex and Opus file formats.

Vorbis Comment does have a proposed GEO_LOCATION field, removing data from this field is as simple as blanking it out in any editor capable of seeing the field.

Here is some of the meta data stored against an audio file encoded as MP3 in the ID3 tag:

[image]

The other method of providing additional meta data with audio files is through the use of companion files- these are usually files with similar names to the audio file they relate to and are usually of the [KML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) or [GPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) data formats. Removing or not distributing these files is sufficient to avoid sharing additional meta data.

When talking about CDs there are two types of meta data - "CD Text" (meta data on the CD) and CDDB (an online meta data resource for CDs).

If you upload a file to Soundcloud, you get multiple kinds of meta data. If you make the file you upload available for download, the file that you download will be the file that you uploaded, including all of the original meta data. In addition to this, Soundcloud has it's own "meta data", this isn't written to the file you upload.

When uploading to YouTube, the file you upload is converted to a video and is no longer the file you uploaded. It's not possible to download the file publicly from YouTube (I don't know if you can download it from within your control panel, as the person whose page it is) so there shouldn't be anything to worry about in this regard.

Obviously there is nothing stopping somebody from encoding the data directly into the audio as audio. In these instances you'd need to know what you're looking for in order to remove it - this could be something obvious (think modem noises) or something sophisticated enough that you might not even [notice](http://lifehacker.com/5807289/how-to-hide-secret-messages-and-codes-in-audio-files) it's [there](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-20629671).

Comment: Thanks. What about more specific meta data like geo tagging or the name of the computer the audio came from?